# qt conflict between QScroller and QScrollBar

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qscrollarea

I found a conflict between QScroller and QScrollBar. So I have a QScrollArea with vertical scrollbar. I also activate a QScroller that allows me to do kinetic scrolling with left click button. But I can't grab the scrollbar handle any more. Because once I grab it, QScroller begins to take over.
This is how I add the QScroller:

```
QScroller::grabGesture(mArea, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture) ;
```

Any idea how can I slove the conflict?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got a solution. I redefined the enterEvent and leaveEvent of QScrollBar, dis-activate and activate the QScroller inside with QScroller::ungrabGesture() QScroller::grabGesture().
It works fine now. Besides, a event filter can also do the job.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue.
It can be avoided by applying the `grabGesture` to the viewport of the `QScrollArea`, instead of the whole widget:

```
QScroller::grabGesture(mArea->viewport(), QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture) ;
```